# asp.net cliente/servidor

Tags: asp.net, webforms

como podria llamar a una funcion del lado servidor desde el lado cliente , que devuelta resultados y usar esos datos del lado del cliente

**codigo del lado del cliente :**

html:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();"</input>
```

javascript:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var variable1 = "medicina"
   //llamo a la funcion GetData //
   //guardo variables cada campo que devuelve la funcion GetData
   //...sigo con el codigo
   }
```

**codigo del lado servidor:**

```
Private Function GetData(variable1 As String) As DataTable
Dim conString As String =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from location where especialidad =@variable1)
        Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crearte en el codebehind del aspx un WebMethod que devuelva los datos que te hacen falta y desde la parte del cliente, por medio de Ajax, llamar a este webmethod.

Posteriormente, una vez recuperados los datos por Ajax, ya los utilizas como creas oportuno desde la parte de cliente.